# Mark-up Validation

Tags: html, xhtml

I am attempting to clean up some HTML after it being chopped and altered many times.

When I go to Validate the page I keep getting a kick back saying this

"end tag for "table" which is not finished"

bit confused as i believe I closed it? here is a sample.

`<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="widthtable" width="650" />`

I also tried

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="widthtable" width="650"< </table>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be aware that `align`, `width` and `border` are obsolete HTML attributes. So are your cell attributes

Comment: @MrLister yes, I said that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the error message more closely.

It says that it has found the end tag (so you **have** closed it) but that it is not finished.

Now [look at the DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1):

> ```
> <!ELEMENT TABLE - -
>      (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)>
> ```

Its children are:

- An optional caption element
- Any number of col and colgroup elements
- An optional thead element
- An optional tfoot element
- At least one tbody element

You haven't added any children at all, so the mandatory first tbody element is missing. This means the table isn't finished when you write the end tag for it.

---

A table without any children doesn't many any sense anyway.

If you have no data, then you can't express that data in the form of a table.

---

NB: With the exception of the `class` attribute, every attribute you have used was superseded by CSS a decade ago.

Comment: The HTML that is being edited was purchased as templates, that have been used extensively. I have a minor working knowledge on the coding side. It seems those tables are being used to position the page? I can post the whole section on the code if that would help?

Comment: @HanleiPrice — Sounds like the table should be removed entirely and replaced with CSS then.

Answer (score -3):

You should close your table tags correctly.

```
<table .. **>**</table>


<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="widthtable" width="650"> </table>
```

Comment: That's just a copy of the last code sample in the question. That doesn't seem sufficient to be an answer.

Comment: recheck the previous code....you havent closed the opening tag of the table, after the width.

Comment: I am not Hanlei Price. This is a good example of why code only answers are low quality. The difference in that game of spot the difference requires horizontal scrolling to detect. If that was the problem, then the problem would have been caused by a typo and the question should be closed, not answered. It isn't the problem though because the validator would not give that error message for that problem.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17941021)

Comment: @ineersa This doesn't answer the question, no matter how sound the advice in it is - tables should not be closed with NESTCs. But that doesn't make it a good answer.